# CSS-Statement to change the color of a button DURING click

Tags: html, css, button, colors

I want to change the color of my button during the click. I didn't find any solution, thats why I'm asking. I don't want to change the color of the button after it was clicked. I want to change the color DURING the click (so the color the button has when you press the button). At the moment the button gets blue while pressing it. (Safari)

Thanks!

```
<input type="button" value="MyButton">
```

Comment: What do you mean "gets blue while pressing it" and how is this different than "DURING" click? Can you also post the CSS you are using now, so that we can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to add `:active` in the `CSS` for your `element`

```css
input[type='button']:active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="MyButton"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was searching for.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)